# Block direct access to PHP files and allow json

Tags: php, ajax, block

I'm trying to block out some files with a php script, however, i want my javascript ajax calls to allow the scripts, i don't know if this is even possible but..

What i do now is,

```
$filename = array('index.php');

$basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(!in_array($basename, $filename)) {
    die('...');
}
```

This will block all files and not index.php, but what if i have an login.php that makes my ajax calls possible?

Comment: i am really not sure what you mean

Comment: Are you using any plug ins to do your AJAX? I believe JQuery and a couple others set a header that you can check.

Comment: This is not possible in a safe way. All request headers can be faked. If you need to do this in order to create safety, you need to rethink your application's security.

Answer (score 2):

When you send a JavaScript AJAX call it adds

> X-Requested-With : XmlHTTPRequest

To the HTTP headers. So if you want to do something in case of an AJAX call you can
check for something like this:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
if($headers['X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    // ...
}
```

Keep in mind that any HTTP client can modify headers, so it doesn't really add any security (but e.g. a browser couldn't call your PHP scripts directly with the default settings).

Comment: ok, well - the case is it doesn't mater if they can see what happends, since they still need the form and everything is being validated with PHP. It's just a simple method to redirect users from another file.