# How to block a php script from being executed directly from address bar?

Tags: php, jquery

I  have something like this:

```
$.getJSON('/scripts/commons/theScriptDoTravelBackInTime.php',{
}, function(){
  // etc.. etc...
}
});
```

Is there a way to stop the php script from being executed simply by a direct call in the
address bar like http://www.myserver/scripts/commons/theScriptDoTravelBackInTime.php ?

Maybe outputting an echo "Hey no cheating !"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block direct access to PHP files and allow json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748276/block-direct-access-to-php-files-and-allow-json)

Comment: Generally speaking, no. What exactly are you trying to do, and who would execute the script in the "legitimate" case and how?

Comment: Both the answers below will block it from "the address bar" but there is no way to truly block everything but ajax.

Comment: @Jon, nothing really dangerous.. but would like to avoid it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the kohana framework uses:

```
   public static function is_ajax()
    {
      return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND 
              strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

basic, not 100% safe, but commonly quoted

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
 //your code
}
```

Comment: There is no 100% secure method, but this is often the one used.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the HTTP-Referer data.  If it's blank, then it came from typing or pasting the URL.  If it's not blank, then that field will show you where the link came from.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: Won't it be blank if the client copies and pastes the URL?

Comment: Yea, if anything it'd be vice versa - or verify the referer comes from an expected source.

Answer (score 0):

If you use zend framework there is a nice way of checking it

```
if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
  //The request was made with JS XmlHttpRequest
}
```